# При обработке переворачивается изображения php

Tags: php, изображения

Подскажите, в чём тут ошибка? В коде не выполняется всё что после `if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) { .... }`

```
               $file_name = $filetodb;
               $maxDim = 2000;
               $quality = 85;

                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize( $file_name );
                if ( $width > $maxDim || $height > $maxDim ) {
                    $ratio = $width/$height;
                    if( $ratio > 1) {
                        $new_width = $maxDim;
                        $new_height = $maxDim/$ratio;
                    } else {
                        $new_width = $maxDim*$ratio;
                        $new_height = $maxDim;
                    }

                        
                        //вращаем изображение
                        $exif = exif_read_data($file_name);

                        //var_dump($exif);
            
                        if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
                            switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
                                case 3:
                                    $file_name= imagerotate($file_name, 180, 0);
                                    break;
                                
                                case 6:
                                    $file_name = imagerotate($file_name, 90, 0);
                                    break;
                                
                                case 8:
                                    $file_name= imagerotate($file_name, -90, 0);
                                    break;
                            }

                        }


                    $src = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents( $file_name ) );
                    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
                    
                    imagecopyresampled( $dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );

                    imagejpeg($dst,$file_name,$quality);
                    imagedestroy( $src );
                    imagedestroy( $dst );
```

Answer (score 1):

Фотография при загрузке заливается как есть. Горизонтально.
Оттого, что ты повернул фотоаппарат, положение матрицы относительно объектива как бы не меняется. То есть, для фотоаппарата все фотографии - горизонтальные. Как на фотопленке: как бы ты ни вертел аппарат, на пленке все фотографии параллельны друг другу. Точно так же сохраняются и файлы в телефоне.

Другое дело, что фотоаппарат может запомнить, как его вертели, и записать текущее положение в метаданные файла с изображением.
А практически все современные программы умеют эту информацю читать, и автоматически поворачивать фотографию. Поэтому у незадачливого зрителя складывается впечатление, что фотографии "заливаются уже повернутыми".

Так что теперь и нашему РНР программисту остается обучить свою программу этой нехитрой премудрости. Я предполагаю, что после заливки фотографии как-то обрабатываются. Вот к этой обработке и надо добавить поворот. Для GD это будет функция imagerotate(), а информацию об исходной ориентации можно получить с помощью функции getImageOrientation(). Если она недоступна - то exif_read_data() или с помощью каких либо ещё библиотек.

Comment: С ориентацией понятно, спасибо, а в чём может быть ошибка в  моём коде не подскажете?

Comment: у вас `exif_read_data` вообще работает?

Comment: Да, определяется `case 6` корректно. но после этого не происходит дальнейшее уменьшение файла. Может что-то с переменными я не так сделал.